# Playing an audio file partially for an Alarm program in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I created an alarm in python and I want to play a the first 10 seconds of an audio track once the alarm time is hit.

I tried using subprocess.call, but I cannot terminate the code after 10 seconds for example:

```py
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/vlc", "/home/panos/Desktop/U TUBE/SRW α3 - Battle God of Steel.webm"])
```

This plays the track, but I don't know how to stop it after 10 seconds and also to not display the actual VLC player while the alarm is on.
What other options do I have ? and is there something I can do with subprocess.
I was thinking that bash has commands to play audio for 10 seconds, so I can call that from `subprocess`, but I don't know anything about bash commands

Comment: given that you dont show your code i am not sure how you expect anyone to help.

Comment: I sure do know about sub-process. But i am not sitting at my desk constantly waiting for you to update your question. I would suggest you read the how to ask guide for future questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: upvoted him now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `subprocess.check_output`, it has `timeout` parameter which you can set it.

```
import subprocess

command = ["/usr/bin/vlc", "/home/panos/Desktop/U TUBE/SRW α3 - Battle God of Steel.webm"]

try:
    x=subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, timeout=5)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as exc:
    print("Command timed out: {}".format(exc))
```

I have test it with the sleep command and it worked as expected.

```
import subprocess

try:
    x = subprocess.check_output(["sleep", "10"], timeout=5)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as exc:
    print("Command timed out: {}".format(exc))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 timeout.py 
Command timed out: Command '['sleep', '10']' timed out after 5 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you that helped alot.

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer helped you, please vote it and mark the question as answered! :)

Comment: I am sorry but it is not letting me vote...i am so sorry.